# iOS 9 Warnings in Xcode - This file is set to build for a version older than the project deployment. Functionality may be limited

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I just updated my mac to the newest OS and Xcode to the newest version and now I have this warning and I have no idea who to get rid of it or what it really means?

Could someone explain it to me?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: To which iOS version are you building your app?

Comment: @vinbhai4u I want to to be compatible for 7.1 and up so the deployment targets are 7.1...

Comment: Are you using any controls that came with XCode 7, StackView?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Select `Main.storyboard` in the project navigator, press <kbd>⌘⌥1</kbd> to show the Identity Inspector and change `Builds for` for something suitable

[image]

Comment: Note: if you have localized you storyboard for other languages - be sure to check all storyboard settings.

Comment: It still does not work for me. My deployment target is 8.3 and even if I set the Builds For value to my deployment target or "even 9.0 and Later" I still get the exact same error warning.

Comment: This worked, but I had to clean my build folder, quit Xcode, delete files in Derived Data, open Xcode and reclean as well.

Answer (score 2):

If changing the minimum build target version does not work for you, try inspecting the XIB source file. Right click on the file -> Open As -> Source Code.

Look for  section near the top, which looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <deployment version="2304" identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="13173"/>
    <capability name="Aspect ratio constraints" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
    <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
    <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
</dependencies>
```

My target build was iOS 9, but my aspect ratio constraint has minToolsVersion 5.1. When I changed it to 9.0 the warning went away.